# Test Class for Approval Process

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller, approval-process

I am trying to set up a test class to test a Visualforce page button which, when clicked, submits a custom object record to an approval process using a controller method.  When I try the test below, I get an error:

> System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was
>   found.:

My only entry criteria is that the Region on the Opportunity starts with "NA", which is does, adn the approval process is active.  Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

**Class for Creating Account and Opp Records:**

```
public class TestCreateRecords {

    // create and insert a new Account record.
        public static Account createAcct(Integer i){ 
        Account acct = new Account();
            acct.Name = 'Test' + i;
            acct.Language__c = 'English';
            acct.Industry = 'Automotive';
            acct.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
            acct.Region__c = 'NA-US-NE';
            acct.BillingCity = 'New York';
            acct.BillingState = 'New York';
            acct.BillingCountry = 'United States';
        return acct;
        }

        public static Opportunity createOppNew (Id acctId){ 
            Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity();
                opp2.AccountId = acctId;
                opp2.Name = 'Test Opportunity - ';
                opp2.StageName = System.Label.Eng_OppStage3;
                opp2.CloseDate = date.newinstance(2020,1,31);
                opp2.Amount = 1000;
                opp2.Region__c = 'NA-US-NE';
            return opp2;
        }
    }
```

**Test Class:**

```
    @Istest (SeeAllData=true)
private class TestControllerDealSumm
{
        Account acct3 = TestCreateRecords.createAcct(0);
        insert acct3;

        Opportunity opp3 = TestCreateRecords.createOppNew(acct3.Id);
        insert opp3;

        Summary__c DS3 = new Summary__c();
            DS3.Opportunity__c = opp3.Id;
            DS3.Agreement_Effective_Date__c = date.newinstance(2025,1,31);
            DS3.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c = 60;
            DS3.Auto_Renewal__c = TRUE;
        Insert DS3;

        ApexPages.StandardController Summ1a = new ApexPages.standardController(opp3);
        VF_SummaryController SummCont1a = new VF_SummaryController(Summ1a);
        SummCont1a.DS.add(DS3);
        SummCont1a.Summary();
        SummCont1a.save();


        ApexPages.StandardController Summ3 = new ApexPages.standardController(DS3);
        DSReviewController SummCont3 = new DSReviewController(Summ3);
        SummCont3.myDS = DS3;
        SummCont3.approve();

        // Create an approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req1.setObjectId(acct3.Id);

        // Submit the approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req1);

        // Verify the result
        System.assert(result.isSuccess());

        System.assertEquals(
            'Pending', result.getInstanceStatus(), 
            'Instance Status'+result.getInstanceStatus());

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class DSReviewController {

    public Summary__c myDS;

    public DSReviewController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.myDS = (Summary__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public pageReference approve() {

        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest approve1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        approve1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
        approve1.setObjectId(myDS.id);

        approve1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(null);
        approve1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);

        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(approve1);

        PageReference RetPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
        RetPage.setRedirect(true);
        return RetPage; 
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) the debug output will show the values for the entering object to each approval process (2) `seeAlldata=true` shouldn't be needed here

Comment: @crop1645 -- Thanks.  1) I look at the debug log and on 1 line it says it finds an approval process, inputs all the data, and then throws the error.  I'm not sure what to look for?  2) I need the seeAlldata = true because there is a custom setting in my instance that throws an error unless I have that line of code.  I couldn't figure out another way of covering the custom setting.

Comment: mock the custom setting just like any other sobject. I tend to do this in a `Util.mockEnv()` method that every testmethod calls

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I figured out my issue.  My Test Class was looking at the Account ID instead of the ID of my newly created custom object (line 32).  I changed that line to `req1.setObjectId(DS3.Id);` and then got an error that the process was already in progress.  This mad me realize that I didn't need the approval process creation from lines 29 - 42, since the process was being triggered by my "approve" controller on lines 17 - 21.  So I removed lines 29 - 42 and now get 100% coverage.  Thanks for the help everyone.  Updated Test class is below:

```
@Istest (SeeAllData=true)
private class TestControllerDealSumm
{
        Account acct3 = TestCreateRecords.createAcct(0);
        insert acct3;

        Opportunity opp3 = TestCreateRecords.createOppNew(acct3.Id);
        insert opp3;

        Summary__c DS3 = new Summary__c();
            DS3.Opportunity__c = opp3.Id;
            DS3.Agreement_Effective_Date__c = date.newinstance(2025,1,31);
            DS3.Net_Payment_Term_Days__c = 60;
            DS3.Auto_Renewal__c = TRUE;
        Insert DS3;

        ApexPages.StandardController Summ1a = new ApexPages.standardController(opp3);
        VF_SummaryController SummCont1a = new VF_SummaryController(Summ1a);
        SummCont1a.DS.add(DS3);
        SummCont1a.Summary();
        SummCont1a.save();


        ApexPages.StandardController Summ3 = new ApexPages.standardController(DS3);
        DSReviewController SummCont3 = new DSReviewController(Summ3);
        SummCont3.myDS = DS3;
        SummCont3.approve();
}
```